# How to redirect after closing modal frame window

Tags: javascript, drupal

I close my modal frame window in javascript with such command 
Drupal.modalFrameChild.triggerParentEvent('childClose', [args, statusMessages]).
But I don't know how to redirect my browser to a specific path after that?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `window.location.href = url;` command. Just use the url to define the location!

Comment: "Drupal.modalFrameChild.triggerParentEvent('childClose');
window.location.href = url;"
it didn't help me, modal window close but redirect didn't go